# Not able to change styling of OptGroup of ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have been trying to change the font and color of the OptGroup but its not changing. I am using emotion css

```
     <Select 
       className={css
         .ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-group-title{
            font-size: 15px;
            color: white;
       }
      >
      <OptGroup
        label="Manager"
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
      </OptGroup>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some `antd` CSS classes that can't be overridden through `CSS-in-JS` like `styled-components` or `emotion`. It depends on when the css style applied within the `antd` implementation (you should inspect the dom tree).

It includes overriding `ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-group-title`, in this case, you only can do it via `.css` file:

```
/* App.css */
.ant-select-dropdown-menu-item-group-title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

// App.jsx
import './App.css';
```